# A problem about covering map and evenly covered neighborhood

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that p : E -> B be a covering map and that B is path-connected and locally path-connected. Then, given y in B, there exists a neighborhood U of y in B that is path-connected and evenly covered by p. Now the inverse image of U by p consists of slices {Va}. Take a point x in E such that p(x)=y and let V' be the slice containing x.

Now the questions is, take any arbitrary neighborhood N of x in X, then how to replace U by a smaller neighborhood of y such that the slice V' containing x can be included in the N? It seems very nontrivial to me...In the text I read, there is no detailed explanation about this. Could anyone give me some more rigorous proof?

Answer (score 2):

You know that $p$ restricted to $V'$ is a homeomorphism between $V'$ and $U$, in particular an open map. If $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, then $x \in \operatorname{Int}(N)$, and define $V'' = V' \cap \operatorname{Int}(A)$, and let replace $U$ by $p[V''] \subset U$, which is open (by the restiction of $p$ being a homeomorphism!) and a neighbourhood of $y$. This is also an evenly covered neighbourhood, and the slice that contains $x$ is precisely $V'' \subset N$. By shrinking $p[V'']$ even further we can assume it is still path-connected (as path connected open neighbourhoods form a local base, and smaller neighbourhoods of an evenly covered neighbourhood are still evenly covered).